# Python: Trim heapq heap so it is only X items long

Tags: python

What would be the fastest way to get the top X items of a heap, as a heap still?

I would figure there is a better way than rebuilding a heap by popping the heap X times.

Comment: Do you actually need to build the whole heap in the first place? If not, just use `nsmallest` (or do the equivalent manually with `heappushpop`), which will not only be faster than building a heap and popping X items (NlogX instead of NlogN), it'll also use a lot less memory (X instead of N).

Answer (score 3):

@Ben is right on all counts, although Python's `heapq` heaps are min-heaps rather than max-heaps:

```
newheap = [heappop(oldheap) for _ in range(X)]  # removes from oldheap
```

is usually as good as it gets.  However, it **can** be faster, and especially so if X is nearly as large as `len(oldheap)`, to do this instead:

```
newheap = sorted(oldheap)[:X]  # doesn't change oldheap
```

At least in CPython, the sort method can take advantage of the partial order already in `oldheap`, and complete sorting the whole list faster than `heappop()` can extract the smallest `X` elements (sorting can need fewer comparisons overall, and the comparisons are the costliest part).  The extreme in this vein is when `X == len(oldheap)` and `oldheap` already happens to be in sorted order.  Then sorting requires a grand total of `X-1` comparisons, while repeatedly popping requires on the order of `X*log(X)` comparisons.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of asymptotic complexity, that's actually the best you can do. You know the front item is the maximal element, and the runner-up is one of its children. But the other child of the root node might be only the 100th biggest, with the higher 98 in the other half of the tree.

Of course, once you've pulled off your X items, you don't need to re-heapify them -- they'll already be sorted, and hence a well-formed binary heap of their own.